# orbeon form data not getting stored in mysql database

Tags: orbeon

I followed the steps to setup the MySQL relational database to get the form data in that database, but I am unable to see the data in database.

I created the `orbeon.xml` file in the `tomcat/conf` folder with the content below:

```
     <Context path="/orbeon"  docBase="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 
           9.0\webapps" reloadable="false" override="true" allowLinking="true">
        <Resource>
              name="jdbc/mysql"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

             auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource"

             initialSize="3"
             maxActive="10"
             maxIdle="10"
             maxWait="30000"

             poolPreparedStatements="true"

             testOnBorrow="true"
             validationQuery="select 1

             username="orbeon"
             password="orbeon"
             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon"/>

         </Context>
```

But when I put below the content below in the `properties-local.xml` file, I am unable to access Form Builder or Form Runner.

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"
    value="mysql"/>
```

Comment: If you get an error in the web browser when accessing Form Builder after doing this setup, I'd recommend you check the `orbeon.log`, and see what is the error that shows up there when you load Form Builder (or Form Runner) in the browser. You'll let me know what you find. ‑Alex

Comment: Did you get a chance to check your `orbeon.log` to see if there was an error when you were loading the webpage making a database access? Or you have maybe found a solution to the problem already? ‑Alex